# AttributeError: 'Second' object has no attribute 'funct'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am attempting to create a custom function for when the "OK" button is clicked in a custom modal.

```
class Second(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        def funct():
            print("This is a test")
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok|QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, self)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.funct)
```

I am able to use both self.reject() and self.accept() without any complications, but when I attempt to use self.funct(), I receive the error message in the title.
None of the suggestions from similar questions seemed to help. Is it something with the QDialogButtonBox in particular?

Comment: As written, `def funct` is indented underneath `def __init__`.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: A nested function creates a local name.  Therefore the name `funct` isn't a member of class Second.

Comment: Yes, that it intentional. I would like to execute some other functions before closing the QDialog instance out. So should I then define funct outside of Second? And if so, how would I go about closing the window if the function is defined outside of the class?

Comment: If you want to execute some tasks before closing the window you should overwrite the closeEvent method

Comment: If you want to close the window from another class you could do it through the same instance. Or you can do it by creating a signal that you then connect with the QDialog.close method, and you only have to issue the signal to close the window.

Comment: In Qt and therefore pyqt is to handle any type of task with events, signals and slots

Comment: `funct` is just a function that you're using as handler for the "accepted" event.  No matter where you define it (whether inside or outside of `__init__`, or anywhere else for that matter), it will run to completion before the dialog instance is destroyed.  Once you are inside the event handler, the user can't interact with the dialog.  But your code can do anything it wants, and the dialog is still in existence. You can access its children and all of its member variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `funct` function is a nested function so it is not part of the `Second` class so it is inappropriate to use the instance (`self`) to access it, what you must do is access directly, for it uses:

```
buttonBox.accepted.connect(funct)
```